# loadData() function on codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to using JavaScript loadData function on CodeIgniter 3?
I have a transaction view that have detail items to be bought, I want to use loadData to load detail view.

This is my file structure:

```
myproject:
 -application
   --controller
     ---admin
       -----dashboard.php
       -----transaction.php
     ---home.php
   --model
     ---mymodel.php
   --view
     ---transaction
       ----transaction_index.php <- the view that I want to use for calling
       ----transaction_detail.php <- the view that I want to call
     ---home.php
```

And my transaction_index main part:

```
<div id="t_detail"></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function loadData(args){
    $("#t_detail").load("<?php echo base_url('admin/transaction/getDetail'); ?>");
}
loadData();

function emptying(args){
    $("#id").val();
    $("#name").val();
    $("#category").val();
    $("#price").val();
    $("#total").val();
}
})
```

My transaction detail just contain table
And my controller

```
public function getDetail(){
    $data['temporary'] = $this->mymodel->getAllData('temporary')->result();
    $data['limit'] = $this->mymodel->countAll('temporary');
    $this->load->view('transaction/transaction_detail', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you are trying to load an HTML view inside of a div using jQuery and CodeIgniter. I would utilize the [$.ajax method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [$.get method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) provided by jQuery since you're already using it.

a javascript code example would be like:

```
 // var site_url returns your codeigniter application's URL by splitting it before index.php.
// if you're using .htaccess or mod_rewrite for pretty urls (no index.php, you may need to find another way to get the URL of your site)

var site_url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.split('index.php')[0] + 'index.php';

//do a GET request for the transaction/getDetail endpoint
$.get(site_url + 'index.php/transaction/getDetail', function(html) {
    //load the HTML returned by the codeigniter controller into the #t_detail element
    $("#t_detail").html(html);
});
```

please mark as the accepted answer if you feel this solves your issue.

Comment: still dont showing anything, must I include 'index.php'? I don't use index.php on my URL, I use .htaccess rewrite, but thanks before

Comment: if you don't use .htaccess, you could try something like `window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname`  ... That will work if your app is not in a sub-directory. If it is in a sub directory, you'll want to get your sites URL in a different manner.

Comment: you say its still not showing anything... are you getting any errors from PHP or Javascript (check via the console)

Comment: I follow another CI project that using script above, and works on them, but not for me, I still learning using CI, can u give me some way using loadData(args) above?